# Aggregate audio device with AirPods doesn't record

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, midi

I used *Audio MIDI Setup* to create two aggregate devices:

1. [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) + MackBook Pro Microphone -> works
2. [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) + AirPods Pro Input -> doesn't work

When I record the screen (⇧⌘5) with #1 it works, capturing my voice from the MacBook microphone, but when I do the same with #2 it does not capture my voice from the AirPods. What am I missing? Is it even possible to screen record while capturing audio from the AirPods?

More context: In both cases I'm connected with my AirPods and I both hear the internal audio output and the recording captures it, as I set the audio output to a multi-device of BlackHole+AirPods.

Comment: I don’t believe it’s possible to aggregate (and have work) multiple *wireless* audio devices.